# how to interpret the nodejs performance tests run through Artillery

Tags: performance-testing, artillery

I'm using Artillery to run some performance tests on a node app.  I'm not sure how to interpret the results.  I get something like

```
All virtual users finished
Summary report @ 11:24:12(+1000) 2019-04-29
  Scenarios launched:  600
  Scenarios completed: 600
  Requests completed:  600
  RPS sent: 19.73
  Request latency:
    min: 1.2
    max: 7.7
    median: 1.7
    p95: 3.1
    p99: 3.8
  Scenario counts:
    0: 600 (100%)
  Codes:
    400: 600
```

Not sure what these results mean for example 
  Request latency
  Codes
  Scenario Counts,

Is there any other more popular tool that can be used as well on a side note for node apps?

Answer (score 0):

Read through the docs page of artillery to understand more about the results.

https://artillery.io/docs/getting-started/

Additionally you can check out `ab` and `wrk` for a more deep analysis of your http endpoints. You'd almost always want to keep and eye on what's happening inside your web server when under load. For that you can take a look at tools like `node-clinic` and `n-solid`.

Comment: thanks for the links, I actually saw the artillery docs before posting the question.  Was a bit confused with Request latency.  I assume this is the time taken for a request to depart from the client and the response come back to the client?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. It is the time duration for a request to complete.